# ViewFlipper inside a viewpager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I want to implement something like this: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html .
My main view is a Viewflipper with two views on opposite sides of cards.How can i implement a viewpager above a viewflipper layout?My layout right now is this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout android:id="@id/FlashCardFront" android:background="#3500ffff style="@style/Fill"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ViewFlipper android:id="@+id/flipper" style="@style/Fill" android:layout_margin="8.0dip">       
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/front" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffffff"  style="@style/Fill">
    <LinearLayout style="@style/FillWrap.LL.FlashCard_Header">

       <ImageButton 
 android:id="@+id/back"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:onClick="true"
 android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
android:background="#00000000"
 />   

        <TextView android:id="@id/TV_CardNo" android:text="0000" android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/Wrap.Text_RightTop" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:id="@id/LL_Card" style="@style/FillWrap.LL.FlashCard_Body">
        <TextView android:id="@id/TV_Word" android:text="Word" style="@style/FillWrap.Text_FlashCard_Word" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout style="@style/FillWrap.LL.FlashCard_Footer">
        <RatingBar android:id="@id/RB_Stars_Front" android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratings_bar" android:numStars="1" android:stepSize="1.0" style="@style/Wrap" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:background="#ffffffff"  style="@style/Fill">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/RearHeader" style="@style/FillWrap.LL.FlashCard_Header">
          <ImageButton 
 android:id="@+id/rear_back"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:onClick="true"
 android:src="@drawable/left_arrow"
android:background="#00000000"
 />   
        <TextView android:id="@id/TV_CardNo" android:text="0000" android:layout_weight="1.0" style="@style/Wrap.Text_RightTop" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/rear_next"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.14"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:onClick="true"
            android:src="@drawable/right_arrow" />       
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@id/LL_Card1" style="@style/FillWrap.LL.FlashCard_Body">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>        </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout style="@style/FillWrap.LL.FlashCard_Footer">
                <TextView android:id="@id/TV_Meaning" android:text="Meaning" style="@style/FillWrap.Text_FlashCard_Meaning" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ViewFlipper>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Did you follow along on that page? What happens if you add the ViewPager as the top level parent view in your layout?

Comment: @Tim I lose my layout if i make the ViewPager top of the ViewFlipper.

Answer (score 0):

The style that is there on the page is accomplished using a library called viewpagerindicator...done by Jake wharton....check how it works

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a `Linearlayout` with the `horizontal` orientation, then add dot image to the layout. And set the code for changing the position of the selected dot inside of the ViewPager pageChangedListner.

Thank you.